# WPF: Prevent ListViewItem from being selected on Shift + Arrow

Tags: wpf, listviewitem, shift

How do I prevent a ListViewItem from being selected when I click on an item and press (Down/Up) Arrow? I don't want to disable it, I just want it to not be selectable on Shift+Arrow. Some of my listviewitems need to be selectable and some others not.

Sample:

[ListViewItem 1]

[ListViewItem 2]

[ListViewItem 3]

User clicks on ListviewItem1, it gets selected.

User then presses SHIFT+DOWN ARROW,=> ListViewItem 2 is not selected.

At this point either ListViewItem3 is selected or it might take another SHIFT+DOWN ARROW to select ListViewItem3 (it doesn't matter as long as it gets selected sometime).

(In my project the actual ListViewItem 2 is actually NOT a regular item on 1 row, it is a vertical item that spans several rows in just one column. My ListView source has a compositecollection of very different items; I am trying to select what appears to be 'regular row items' only)

Comment: Can you share any of the XAML from this UI element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a `Property` of your class such as `IsSelected`. Here is some sample code for what that `Property` would look like.

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return isSelected;           //return the value of isSelected
    }
    set
    {
        if (isSelectable)            //if the item is allowed to be selected
        {                            //then update the value of isSelected
            isSelected = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }
}
```

In this example it is assumed that **"isSelectable"** is a value that is set in the constructor when your class is being initialized. If you don't already have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented, it needs to be... and the `PropertyChanged` event needs to be declared.

In addition, you will also want a `Style` that binds the selection of `ListView` items to this property. Here is an example of a `Style` that could accomplish this.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

You can take this one step further, and also bind to the `Focusable` `Property`. This will make it so that when you press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> it will *skip* any items that you cannot select and select the next item that is selectable. I would accomplish this in a manner similar to the following.

```
public bool Focusable
{
    get
    {
        return isSelectable;    //if the item is selectable, then it is focusable
    }
}
```

You would also need to create a binding for this in your `Style` by creating an additional `Setter`. This could be done the following way, inside the same `Style` as before.

```
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="{Binding Focusable}"/>
```

Try it both with and without that last `Setter` and see which implementation suits your needs best.

--------- UPDATE ---------

If you would like to only select items on mouse click, you could do so by subscribing to the `ListView` `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event. Inside of the event handler, you would need to first [get the clicked item](http://blog.nostatic.org/2007/12/wpf-listview-getting-clicked-item.html), and call a function on your class which will override the selection. Here is an example of how that is done.

This function would exist in your UI code-behind and must be subscribed to by your `ListView`:

```
private void myListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListViewItem))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    object obj = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(dep);

    if (obj is MyClass)
    {
        foreach (MyClass i in myListView.Items)
        i.OverrideSelect(false);    //unselect all items

        MyClass item = (MyClass)obj;
        item.OverrideSelect(true);      //select the item clicked
    }
}
```

(Note: replace "MyClass" with your class type).

This function would exist in your class file:

```
public void OverrideSelect(bool selected)
{
    isSelected = selected;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How about if I want my ListViewItem selectable when clicked but not selectable on Shift+Arrow?

Comment: @bayedbest anytime you want to do things "only on click" the code starts to get a little messy, but I've updated my answer to the best of my ability based on your additional requirement.

Comment: great, thanks. So this selects an item on click, does it make sure that it does not get selected any other way? (Like not on drag-select or shift+arrow)

Comment: @bayedbest, yes I think so. I tried it myself and was not able to drag-select. You still can't select on shift+arrow based on the original solution. Hopefully it covers all cases.